# Controle de estoque e vendas

Tags: c, struct

Olá, este progrgrama é um controle de estoque, o que ele pede esta no primeiro `printf` do programa, um controlador de estoque e venda so com struct. Os casos 3 e 4 estao com problemas, pois eu nao concigo pegar as informações dos itens cadastrados. O caso 2 tambem tem problema mas não sei explicar o motivo. Caso alguem quiser testar rodar o programa eu ficaria grato. O IDE que uso (falcon C++ mais recente) nao identifica nenhum erro,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct produto
{
    char cod;
    float compra;
    float venda;
    float preco;
    int qdt;
    float lucro;
    char descricao[100];
    char nome[50];

};

int main()
{
    int opc;
    int i;
    int per;
    float lucro;
    int ven;

    struct produto cadastrar[40];

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    printf("1-Cadatrar produto\n2-Lucro total\n3-Conferir estoque\n4-Venda\n0-Sair\n");
    scanf("%d", &opc);

    fflush(stdin);

    switch(opc)
    {
    case 1:
        puts("Olá, cadastre um item");

        for(i=0; i<40; i++)
        {
            puts("Nome:");
            gets(cadastrar[i].nome);
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("Código:");
            scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("Descrição:");
            gets(cadastrar[i].descricao);
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("Quantidade:");
            scanf("%d", &cadastrar[i].qdt);
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("Valor da compra:");
            scanf("%f", &cadastrar[i].compra);
            fflush(stdin);
            puts("Preço:");
            scanf("%f", &cadastrar[i].preco);
            fflush(stdin);

            puts("gostaria de cadastrar outro produto?");
            puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
            scanf("%d", &per);

            if(per!=1)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                return main();
            }

            else if(per==1)
            {
                system("cls");
            }

            fflush(stdin);

        }

        return main();

    case 2:
        for(i=0; i<40; i++)
        {
            if(cadastrar[i].venda==0)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                system("cls");
                printf("Não foi feito nenhuma venda:\n");
                return main();
            }   

        else if(cadastrar[i].venda>0)
        {
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("%.2f", cadastrar[i].venda);
        }   

        }

    case 3:
        for(i=0;i<40;i++)
        {
            fflush(stdin);

            puts("Código do produto:");
            scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);//toda vez que é digitado substitui o codigo do item, e zera o resto das variaveis na possição
            fflush(stdin);

            if(cadastrar[i].qdt<12)
            {
                printf("%s", cadastrar[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Produto no fim:\t\t%d\n\n", cadastrar[i].qdt);
                system("pause");
            }

            else if(cadastrar[i].qdt>11)
            {
                puts(cadastrar[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Qtd:t\t%d\n\n", cadastrar[i].qdt);
                system("pause");

            }

            if(cadastrar[i].qdt==0)
            {
                puts(cadastrar[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Item em falta");
            }

            fflush(stdin);

            puts("gostaria de cadastrar outro produto?");
            puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
            scanf("%d", &per);

            if(per!=1)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                return main();
            }

            else if(per==1)
            {
                system("cls");
            }

            fflush(stdin);
        }

        return main();


    case 4:

        for(i=0; i<40; i++)
        {
            puts("Código do produto:");//toda vez que é digitado substitui o codigo do         item, e zera o resto das variaveis na possição
            scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Preço:\t\t%.2f", cadastrar[i].preco);
            printf("Qtd:\t\t%d", cadastrar[i].qdt);

            fflush(stdin);
            ven=0;

            printf("Vender?/n1-sim 2-não:\n");
            scanf("%d", &ven);

            fflush(stdin);

            if(ven==1)
            {
                cadastrar[i].qdt--;
                cadastrar[i].venda=cadastrar[i].preco;
                lucro=cadastrar[i].venda;
            }

            else if(ven==2)
            {
                return main();
            }


            fflush(stdin);

            per=0;

            puts("gostaria de cadastrar outro produto?");
            puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
            scanf("%d", &per);

            if(per!=1)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                return main();
            }

            else if(per==1)
            {
                system("cls");
            }

            fflush(stdin);

            fflush(stdin);
        }

    case 0:
        fflush(stdin);

        system("cls");
        break;

    default:
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("opção invalida, digite outra opção\n");w

        return main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

a minha duvida é a seginte, quando eu cadastro um produto e depois vou vender ou conferir estoque, indiferente do codigo que vou digitar nao eh oo mesmo

Código editavel:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct produto
{
    char cod;
    float compra;
    float venda;
    float preco;
    int qdt;
    float lucro;
    char descricao[100];
    char nome[50];

};

int main()
{
    int opc;
    int i;
    int per;
    float lucro;
    int ven;

    struct produto cadastrar[40];

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    while(opc!=0)
    {
        printf("1-Cadatrar produto\n2-Lucro total\n3-Conferir estoque\n4-Venda\n0-Sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &opc);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(opc)
        {
        case 1:
            puts("Olá, cadastre um item");

            for(i=0; i<40; i++)
            {
                puts("Nome:");
                gets(cadastrar[i].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                puts("Código:");
                scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);
                fflush(stdin);
                puts("Descrição:");
                gets(cadastrar[i].descricao);
                fflush(stdin);
                puts("Quantidade:");
                scanf("%d", &cadastrar[i].qdt);
                fflush(stdin);
                puts("Valor da compra:");
                scanf("%f", &cadastrar[i].compra);
                fflush(stdin);
                puts("Preço:");
                scanf("%f", &cadastrar[i].preco);
                fflush(stdin);

                puts("gostaria de cadastrar outro produto?");
                puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
                scanf("%d", &per);

                if(per!=1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                    break;
                }

                else if(per==1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                }

                fflush(stdin);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            for(i=0; i<40; i++)
            {
                if(cadastrar[i].venda==0)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    system("cls");
                    printf("Não foi feito nenhuma venda:\n");
                    break;
                  } 

                else if(cadastrar[i].venda>0)
                {
                    fflush(stdin);

                    printf("%.2f", cadastrar[i].venda);
                }   
            }
            break;

        case 3:

            for(i=0;i<40;i++)
            {
                fflush(stdin);

                puts("Código do produto:");
                scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);
                fflush(stdin);

                if(cadastrar[i].qdt<12)
                {
                    printf("%s", cadastrar[i].nome);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Produto no fim:\t\t%d\n\n", cadastrar[i].qdt);
                    system("pause");
                }

                else if(cadastrar[i].qdt>11)
                {
                    puts(cadastrar[i].nome);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Qtd:t\t%d\n\n", cadastrar[i].qdt);
                    system("pause");

                }

                if(cadastrar[i].qdt==0)
                {
                    puts(cadastrar[i].nome);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Item em falta");
                    system("pause");
                }

                fflush(stdin);

                puts("gostaria de pesquisar outro produto?");
                puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
                scanf("%d", &per);

                if(per!=1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                    break;
                }

                else if(per==1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                }

                fflush(stdin);
            }

            break;

        case 4:

            for(i=0; i<40; i++)
            {
                puts("Código do produto:");
                scanf("%s", &cadastrar[i].cod);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Preço:\t\t%.2f", cadastrar[i].preco);
                printf("Qtd:\t\t%d", cadastrar[i].qdt);

                fflush(stdin);
                ven=0;

                printf("Vender?/n1-sim 2-não:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ven);

                fflush(stdin);

                if(ven==1)
                {
                    cadastrar[i].qdt--;
                    cadastrar[i].venda=cadastrar[i].preco;
                    lucro=cadastrar[i].venda;
                }

                else if(ven==2)
                {
                    break;
                }


                fflush(stdin);

                per=0;

                puts("gostaria de cadastrar outro produto?");
                puts("1-sim\t2-nao");
                scanf("%d", &per);

                if(per!=1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("finalização de cadastramento de produto\n");
                    break;
                }

                else if(per==1)
                {
                    system("cls");
                }

                fflush(stdin);
            }
            break;

        case 0:
            fflush(stdin);

            system("cls");
            break;

        default:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("opção invalida, digite outra opção\n");

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema do seu codigo e que voce chama varias vezes a funcao `main`. Alem de ser meio esquisito, o que voce acaba fazendo e redeclarando tudo, inclusive seu vetor de `produto`.

Uma possivel solucao e colocar a leitura da opcao em um `while(opc != 0)` e, ao final dele, ler uma nova opcao.

So alguns outros comentarios:

1. Nao use a funcao `gets`. O proprio compilador emite um warning (engracado na minha opniao): "the gets function is dangerous and should not be used". Isso porque ela nao tem um tamanho maximo para a string que ela vai ler. Use o `fgets`:

   fgets(stdin, str, 128);

   ou algo assim.
2. Para usar o `scanf` e ler um caracter, como o seu `cod`, a sintaxe e:

   scanf("%c", &variavel);

   e nao `%s`, como voce esta fazendo, que le strings. Alem disso, quando se usa o `scanf` para ler strings voce nao deve colocar o `&`:

   scanf("%s", string);

Comment: eu coloquei ums area de codigo editavel tá obrigado

Comment: So inicialize `opc` para algo diferente de `0`.

Comment: mas `opc` já é diferente de 0

Comment: Nao quando o programa comeca. Voce usar o valor de `opc` no while sem dar valor para ele.

Comment: acho que agora eu intendi foi mal sou dislexo entao, caso eu apertar enter vai sair?

Comment: não, depende do valor que tem na localização memória que ele ganha quando é declarado. como isso é meio aleatório, é sempre bom você colocar um valor.

Comment: ok muito obrigado